# Unable to see All columns of list in result which is generated by Caml Query

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api

here I am passing caml query to REST Api to get some result on sharepoint online 2016,
the same query works fine on sharepoint 2013.
my caml query is as below

```
var viewXml = "";
    viewXml = {
        ViewXml: "<View>" +
            "<Query>" +
            "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>" +
            "</Query>" +
            "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='AlternateText' /><FieldRef Name='VideoThumbnail' /><FieldRef Name='doc1' /><FieldRef Name='docType' /></ViewFields>"+
            "<RowLimit>" + itemLimit + "</RowLimit>" +
            "</View>"

    }

 $.ajax({
        url: siteCollectionURL + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Latest%20Data')/GetItems(query=@v1)?" +
       "@v1=" + JSON.stringify(viewXml),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
},
      error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
```

here i can see all columns except **VideoThumbnail** which is **Publishing** type field